# How to confirm the application by antivirus when using the NAudio library

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio, antivirus

I use the NAudio library in my Windows Form Application.

The software runs well ,only when I click on the record button, the antivirus sends this message.

[image: ThisImage]

The antivirus I use is Kaspersky.

This software is not a virus and is activated only by the user to record the sound and press the record button.

How can I prevent this message from my own antivirus and other antiviruses?

Comment: It's _not_ marking it as a virus, it's confirming the application is allowed to receive an audio stream, which is a [Kaspersky feature](https://support.kaspersky.com/KIS/2019/en-US/94351.htm)

Comment: #stuard I tested a lot of audio recording software on the system. None of them send this message when recording. Do you have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Make sure you are checking on `Sign the ClickOnce manifests` in project property

Comment: `How can I prevent this message from my own antivirus and other antiviruses?` Get rid of antiviruses, it's 2021. Otherwise, false positives are a common thing.